# How to get the ~/.bashrc to work in the native terminal application in Centos?

Tags: centos, terminal, bashrc

The problem I had was to get the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` and/or `.profile` scripts to execute by default when using the native Gnome terminal application.

I found a number of references which told me in order to get these to "run" you needed to have an interactive session with login but none of the threads I found explained how to do this with the native terminal application.

So my question is how do you get the .bashrc and .bash_profile scripts to run on Centos every time you use the Terminal Application on the Gnome desktop?

Comment: I have edited my question and trust this clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of this I will answer my own question.

So to get this to work:

1. Open the terminal application in Centos (In the Applications\Accessories\Terminal)
2. Select the Edit\Current Profile (If you want to make this the default for your current profile)
3. Select the "Title and Command" tab and tick the option "Run command as login shell"

This then ensures that when you fire up terminal it executes the .profile and .bashrc sourcing.

Comment: `.bashrc` should always be sourced.

Comment: @muru Actually, on a few distributions, this file is never sourced by default. There is no requirement whatsoever when it comes to this, it all depends on what `.profile` and `/etc/profile` do.

Comment: @bated: that's not the answer, that's a hackish workaround.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith Perhaps I should have said ".. in non-login shells", which the terminals open by default.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith: not quite right ... the plain /etc/profile & ~/.profile are there in case none of bash's actual initialisation files are present, and for reasons of backwards compatibility with sh.

Comment: @tink this is nothing to do with a hackish workaround.  My question is simple:  How do you get ~/.bashrc to work with the native terminal application built into the gnome desktop?

Comment: @bated: I understood that perfectly fine. But forcing every open window to become a login shell is not the right way to do this; the question is why your login manager doesn't pull it in, or why your terminal doesn't inherit the values from ~/.bashrc if the login manager did do its job.

Comment: @tink surely that must be by design as why else would Centos offer this option in the Terminal Application Profile?

Answer (score 1):

If your terminal starts a normal `bash` session, that `bash` will read in `~/.bashrc`. If you have additional commands in `~/.bash_profile`, those will only be read by the login shell and not by a non-login bash start.

You can easily source `~/.bashrc` from `~/.bash_profile` with something like:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
. ~/.bashrc
fi
```

And then move everything else from `.bash_profile` into `~/.bashrc`. Please note that `~/.bash_login` is only read by the login shell if `~/.bash_profile` is not found, and and `~/.profile` are only if `~/.bash_login` is not found.

This will work for any terminal program.

Comment: Hi @Anthon this does not work if you use the native terminal application from the gnome desktop.  I tried a number of different variations of this, including `.profile` and the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`

Comment: @bated What exactly does not work? Did you put all your bash stuff in `.bashrc` as I indicated. This works for me and I have about 35 instances of bash open in as many terminal tabs. The only thing that setting "Run command as login shell" does is providing `--login` to bash, but if `~/.bash_login` is almost empty (apart from the 3 lines I gave), the difference is unnoticeable.

Comment: The answer you provide is one of the first things I tried. However I could not get ~/.bash_profile to source (tried putting in a simple echo).  I deduced that the terminal application must be using a non-login shell which is why this was not firing.